# Totalizar valores da coluna duma tabela HTML, com resultado decimais

Tags: javascript, html, table, dom, matemática

Eu preciso exibir o resultado total somando os valores que contem a coluna valor:

```js
            var linha=document.getElementsByClassName("calcular");
            var resultado=document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = 0;

            for (var i=0; i < linha.length; i++) {
                resultado += parseInt(linha[i].innerHTML);
            }

            document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = resultado;
```

```css
        table {
            margin: 5px;
            float: left;
            width: 564px;
            padding: 6px;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 10pt;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
        }

        th {
            background-color: slateblue;
            color: white;
        }

        tr td {
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

```html
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>NOME</th>
                    <th>VALOR</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>Beltrano</td>
                    <td class="calcular">10.50</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>Fulano</td>
                    <td class="calcular">05.98</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>Ciclano</td>
                    <td class="calcular">25.00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> &nbsp; </td>
                    <td> &nbsp; </td>
                    <td> &nbsp; </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> TOTAL </td>
                    <td> &nbsp; </td>
                    <td id="total"> &nbsp; </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

**O *script* funciona em parte**, mas não consegui fazer com que me dê o resultado total com as casas decimais(depois do ponto).

- Como resposta, me retorna: **40**
- Quando deveria me retorna: **41.48**

Pelo menos é assim que imagino que deve ser.

Se puxar isso em uma matriz `array`, pra interagir entre os índices dá pra resolver ou tô enganado?

Ou isso resolve com apenas mais alguma **expressão aritmética**

Comment: não é só trocar o `parseInt` por `parseFloat`?

Comment: melhor que usar o `parseInt/Float` é usar `+`: `resultado += +linha[i].innerHtml;`

Comment: @MarceloUchimura  Seu comentário se fez [juz](https://www.significados.com.br/jus/) ao problema que mais me valeu como DICA! Agradeço desde, ja.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função `parseInt()` retorna qualquer valor inteiro que possa extrair da string que lhe é passada.

```
parseInt(10.50) // 10
```

portanto no loop `for` está somando a parte inteira das strings retornadas

No loop `for` utilize a função [**Number**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dwab3ed2(v=vs.94).aspx) ou  [**parseFloat**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) e no resultado final  [**toFixed(2)**](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/scripting/javascript/reference/tofixed-method-number-javascript)

```js
 var linha=document.getElementsByClassName("calcular");
 var resultado=document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = 0;

     for (var i=0; i < linha.length; i++) {
         resultado += Number(linha[i].innerHTML);
     }

 document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = resultado.toFixed(2);
```

```css
        table {
            margin: 5px;
            float: left;
            width: 564px;
            padding: 6px;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 10pt;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
        }

        th {
            background-color: slateblue;
            color: white;
        }

        tr td {
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

```html
<table>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>NOME</th>
                    <th>VALOR</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>Beltrano</td>
                    <td class="calcular">10.50</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>Fulano</td>
                    <td class="calcular">05.98</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>Ciclano</td>
                    <td class="calcular">25.00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> &nbsp; </td>
                    <td> &nbsp; </td>
                    <td> &nbsp; </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> TOTAL </td>
                    <td> &nbsp; </td>
                    <td id="total"> &nbsp; </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

> Use a função `Number()` quando seu script não estiver preocupado com a precisão do valor e preferir deixar que a string de origem controle se o valor é um número de ponto flutuante ou um inteiro.

**O operador `+` pode te surpreender, dependendo da forma que você o usa.**

- Todo mundo sabe que o operador `+` serve para ao menos duas coisas: somar números e concatenar strings!

> Ao invés de usar a função `Number` ou `parseFloat`  poderíamos usar o próprio operador `+` para converter-lo em numero.

**Veja como:**

```
resultado += +(linha[i].innerHTML);
```

Testando

```js
     var linha=document.getElementsByClassName("calcular");
     var resultado=document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = 0;

         for (var i=0; i < linha.length; i++) {
             resultado += +(linha[i].innerHTML);
         }

     document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = resultado.toFixed(2);
```

```css
            table {
                margin: 5px;
                float: left;
                width: 564px;
                padding: 6px;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 10pt;
                color: white;
                text-align: center;
            }

            th {
                background-color: slateblue;
                color: white;
            }

            tr td {
                background-color: white;
                color: black;
                text-align: center;
            }
```

```html
    <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>NOME</th>
                        <th>VALOR</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>01</td>
                        <td>Beltrano</td>
                        <td class="calcular">10.50</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>02</td>
                        <td>Fulano</td>
                        <td class="calcular">05.98</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>03</td>
                        <td>Ciclano</td>
                        <td class="calcular">25.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> &nbsp; </td>
                        <td> &nbsp; </td>
                        <td> &nbsp; </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> TOTAL </td>
                        <td> &nbsp; </td>
                        <td id="total"> &nbsp; </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

> O sinal de mais `+` é considerado sobrecarregado, o que significa que ele realiza uma ação diferente, dependendo do seu contexto.

Comment: Grato por sua participação e preocupação na explicação, ficando objetivo e claro. É uma resposta a altura da pergunta. Acho que tô mesmo por fora de algumas sintaxe e/ou semântica do tipo `Number()` e `toFixed()` não me lembro destes métodos, tem algum link sobre o assunto que possa me apontar?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/scripting/javascript/reference/tofixed-method-number-javascript

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dwab3ed2(v=vs.94).aspx